# OPEN MOBILE API Issue with MI and OPPO device

Tags: android, open-mobile-api

its working with samsung and other device

nstallation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/in.sample.xxx-1: Package in.sample.xxxxx requires unavailable shared library org.simalliance.openmobileapi; failing!.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove that app from the phone second space that is in device. The MI and OPPO device are always creating this type of problem. I was also facing the same problem in mi devices then i remove the app from mobile second space and after that i am able to install the app in that devices

Comment: have you uninstall the app properly from the device ?